# What redirect URL to use when redirecting ionic for third party webflow

Tags: android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a ionic mobile app in which i want to redirect to a thirdparty webflow which requests users' consent and redirects to the callback url which i should specific for me to grab the token as permission token to make further API calls. Since ionic itself is a html5 mobile app, what do i specify for the redirect url so the control comes back to my mobile app?

Answer (score 4):

## abstract:

This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but it works pretty well.

The Idea is that you use *$cordovaInAppBrowser* to open a webview and listen for events, namely 
`$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart`

and

`$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror`

you can then look at the error and event arguments that are passed and use those to determine if you want to call

`$cordovaInAppBrowser.close();`

which will return you to your ionic app

## code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']).controller('AppCtrl', function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {
    $scope.openThirdPartyWhatever = function() {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        var options = {
          location: 'yes',
          clearcache: 'no',
          toolbar: 'yes'
        };
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://www.myAwesomeSite.com', '_blank', options)
      });
    };

    //at some point your app tries to load 'http://localhost:8100/send-me-back-to-app'
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function(e, event) {
      //and this function is called, so you do something like
      if(event.url === 'http://localhost:8100/send-me-back-to-app'){
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
      }
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function(e, event) {
      $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
      alert('sorry, something went wrong');
    });
  });
```

## helpful links:

https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you will need to handle popup and redirects, you will need to install the cordova  "inappbrowser" plugin in order to be able to open the thrid party webflow inside the app browser and then go back to normal.

Please take a look at this article in where they are explaining how to deal with facebook authentification using the firebase login methods with Ionic and cordova. It describes very similar steps that you will need to tackle your problem.

[Firebase simple login with Ionic and Cordova](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html)

If you are in a rush start from "Getting It Working in the Emulator" but I recommend reading all the article quickly.

I am not sure which kind of third party webflow are you using, but maybe this could help you:
[Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/apps/)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and found this plugin:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme/blob/d1432ecfff63678a3155804839dda21607706e72/README.md