# How to redirect to an Ionic app's base URL?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am building an app using the Ionic platform.

I have a requirement which follows the following flow:

app home -> external link ---> unknown process flow ---> app home

A redirection on the client is triggered in the process of the external link process flow, this is where I need to provide the app's home page.

What URL should I be using to redirect to the app's home page.

Things I have tried:

I used

> window.location.origin + "/#/app/home"

which worked for development.

However this fails in the actual app.

I basically need to provide a URL that loads the app's home page to the web view.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553639/what-redirect-url-to-use-when-redirecting-ionic-for-third-party-webflow/35245584#35245584 see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35245584/1854779

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin does exactly what you need:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme/blob/d1432ecfff63678a3155804839dda21607706e72/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but unanswered.

I was working on this... Run your app then run chrome remote, there, you should see the url. Basically, with ionic this is what I figured out how to redirect to base url

```
  $scope.goHome = function() {
        window.open('file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/app/home', '_self')
  }
```

You're going to need to figure out folder escaping (if you have any) but this can get you going.