# Ionic 3 and Identity server 4 sample code

Tags: ionic3, identityserver4

Can somebody point me the to some sample code, where I can look into all the integration in between ionic3 and identity server 4.

Comment: Which library should I use: oidc-client.js or https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS?

As per I understood here https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/389#issuecomment-319431549, I should use AppAuth-JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki). See some samples below on the page. There is no direct reference to Ionic, but you can see Angular2 examples.
Additionally, I see no answers for any OIDC-related questions on Ionic forums, but there is a [question](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-oauth-2-implicit-grant-flow-spoofing-issue/120272) where the author doubt if exposing client_id, redirect_uri and scopes is a problem. I think it is not, since implicit flow is secured with user credentials. You should not of course provide any direct application level access for such clients. You can use [delegation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html) instead.

[Here](https://github.com/markphillips100/oidc-cordova-demo/issues) is a complete example of authentication with Cordova

Comment: What would be the redirect uri, as ionic application will not have any domain address.

Comment: typically for mobiles that's something internal, such as *com.organisation.application.dev:/oauth2callback*

Comment: a better answer: "The Idea is that you use $cordovaInAppBrowser to open a webview and listen for events, namely $cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart

and

$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror

you can then look at the error and event arguments that are passed and use those to determine if you want to call

$cordovaInAppBrowser.close();

which will return you to your ionic app"

Comment: from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553639/what-redirect-url-to-use-when-redirecting-ionic-for-third-party-webflow

Comment: For more elegant custom url chema handling, the following plugin could be used: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

Comment: Below is my code to get the userInfo. If the info is not present in the session storage then it will ask the identity server and opens in the mobile browser. Do you know how can I use this code in the InAppBrowser methods in the ionic?


new Oidc.UserManager(this.config).getUser().then(function (user: any) {
                if (user) {
                    _user = user;
                }
                else {
                    _user = {};
                }
            });

Comment: If you involve OIDC Client, PopupManager will do that for you, something like:         `ngOidcClient.signinPopup().then(function (user) {if (!!user){/*Logged in*/}});`  But that's the truth, oidc client from Identity does not support pkce. If you wish to support, you can try to look into this https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova-oidc-sample, probably. But pkce is not a requirement to start working.

Comment: I could not make it work after deployed on my android phone, it works with browser. So I have attached the sample code https://files.fm/u/6ckejh6x here. After node_modules installed. When press secure button, it will ask for credentials: testuser@gmail.com and password: testuser